# Angular fails to parse string from api call (web core 3)

Tags: json, angular, parsing

Controller code:

```
 [Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class AjaxController : ControllerBase
{
    ApplicationDbContext dbContext = null;
    public AjaxController(ApplicationDbContext ctx)
    {
        dbContext = ctx;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("GetString")]
    public string GetString()
    {
        return "Hello World";
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("GetCategories")]
    public Category[] GetCategories()
    {
        return dbContext.Categories.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Angular code:

```
http.get<string>(baseUrl + 'api/ajax/GetString').subscribe(result => {
      console.log(result);
    }, error => console.error(error));
```

While Angular can parse without error the GetCategories endpoint, it cannot parse the much simpler GetString. Why? The error in the console is:

error: SyntaxError: "JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data"
​​text: "Hello World"

I tried wit Postman and the response is just fine, see screenshot:
[image: screenshot of Postman]

Comment: What does the response data look like - can you `console.log` it? The error to me indicates that there is invalid JSON

Comment: I have written what the console says it's a parsing error. It cannot parse to string the response data.

Comment: it says also: headers: Object { normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, lazyInit: lazyInit()

Comment: I tried with Postman and it can parse it just fine, I get a proper response

Comment: Can you include a text dump of the response or a screenshot of Postman? Seems to me like the response type isn't matching

Comment: I added the screenshot

Comment: Your request dataType is 'JSON' but your action returned 'text' not a JSON.

Comment: Postman isn't parsing the data, it is displaying it. See my answer for details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is your response from `GetString` is returning just a string of value `Hello World` as shown by the screenshot from Postman. The `GetCategories` endpoint must be returning valid JSON if you are getting a valid response.

By default Angular assumes the response type of a `HttpRequest` to be of type `json`.

To fix this, specify as the second parameter to `http.get()` the `responseType` expected from the server which in your case for the `GetString` endpoint will be `'text'`. So your `http.get()` call should look like the following:

```js
http.get<string>(baseUrl + 'api/ajax/GetString', { responseType: 'text' }).subscribe(result => {
    console.log(result);
  }, error => console.error(error));
```

If your intention was to return valid JSON from `GetString` then you need to format the response from your server as appropriate.

See the Angular documentation on [HttpRequest - responseType](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpRequest#responseType). I've included a copy below.

> `responseType: 'arraybuffer' | 'blob' | 'json' | 'text'`
>
> The expected response type of the server.
>
> This is used to parse the response appropriately before returning it to the requestee.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I solved the problem by converting the string to json format:public string GetString()
        {
            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject( "Hello World");
        }